# Haskell monadic IO

Tags: haskell, types, io, monads

```
compute fp = do
    text <- readFile fp
    let (a,b) = sth text
    let x = data b 
    --g <- x
    putStr $ print_matrix $ fst $ head $ x
```

It works when i get only first element but i want do this for all element on the list of pair.
When i write g<- x i got   Couldn't match expected type `IO t0'
                with actual type [([[Integer]], [[Integer]])]

Comment: `let x = data b` I'm confused.  `data` is a keyword in Haskell for defining types.  That line is a syntax error as it stands.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're inside the IO Monad here, so any time you write a "bind" arrow `<-`, the thing on the right side has to be an IO operation. So the short answer is, you don't want to use `<-` on the value `x`.

Now, it looks like you want to call print_matrix for each element of a list rather than a single element. In that case I think Macke is on the right track, but I would use mapM_ instead:

```
mapM_ (putStr . print_matrix . fst) x
```

should do the trick.

The reason is that you are explicitly saying you want to `putStr` each element, one at a time, but you don't care about the result of `putStr` itself.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like [mapM](http://zvon.org/other/haskell/Outputprelude/mapM_f.html) might fit your bill: `Monad a => (b -> a c) -> [b] -> a [c]`

It's used to apply a monadic function to a list, and get a list back, in the monad

Comment: @XYZ: Glad to help! Note that here SO you should 'accept' the answer which helped you solve your problem by clicking the green arrow. (And upvote all answers which are helpful.)